# IBM API Connect - Can custom connectors be exposed via UI?

Tags: ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, strongloop, apiconnect

In SLC ARC the list of connectors available (when creating datasources and thus generating models) via the UI was hard-coded ([link to overview of issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-workspace/issues/245)) Does the same hold true for API Connect?

Effectively, I'd like to create a fork of the mssql connector to address some issues with how schemas are processed when generating models from existing tables. If I create such a connector, will I be able to install it so that I can utilize it via the GUI (again, I could not via SLC ARC due to hard-coding). Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: I've installed the loopback-connector-redis connector into a throwaway project. When I spin up APIC it does *not* appear on the data sources screen. So, rephrasing my question: are there settings or otherwise that would allow such connectors to be included. Ideally, APIC would scan my project and determine what I have installed, exposing those connectors.

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, the list is currently fixed and doesn't detect additional installed connectors.

If you want to use your own custom connector, create a new datasource using the API Designer, select the MSSQL connector and fill in the values per usual.

Next, you'll need to open a file on your system to tweak the connector target.

In your project directory, open `./server/datasources.json` and you should see the datasource you just created. Then, just change the `connector` value to the name of the custom version you created, save, and continue developing your APIs like normal.

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "DB2 Customers": {
    "host": "datbase.acme-air.com",
    "port": 50000,
    "database": "customers",
    "password": "",
    "name": "Customer DB",
    "connector": "db2-custom",
    "user": "mhamann@us.ibm.com"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, you're now on your own in terms of managing datasources, as they won't show up in the Designer's datasource editor. They *will* still be usable in other parts of the Designer, so you can connect up your models, etc.

Comment: @JP. did this help solve your issue? If so can you please mark the question as answered.